# Rotate feature shapefile with certain pivot point and angle?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I want to rotate a line feature using certain pivot point and angle, but I can not find what tool to use. If rotating a raster, I can simply use Rotate tool, and there I can easily specify the pivot point and rotation angle. But what should I do if I want to rotate a feature? I know I can simply use "Edit Feature" and "Rotate" toolbar, but it does not provide me the way to specify the pivot point and angle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you select a feature, select the rotate tool, and then press the "A" key, you can enter a rotation angle. As for the pivot point, you can drag the "x" that marks the rotation spot with the rotate tool and snap it to any spot along the feature.